# Set edittext increase upto 3 lines while typing in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to set my editText to increase upto 3 lines only while I am typing. I tried minlines but it shows the 3 line edittext even before the user types anything. I tried even wrap_content but nothing works. Please can anybody help with this?

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="#5f6799"
            >


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edComments"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.95"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                 android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:maxLength="140"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Write your comment here"
                android:textColor="@color/my_dark_gray"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try adding textChanged Listener and then in OnTextChanged method set Minlines to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys. Vivek Mishra's solution worked for me.

```
edComments.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            edComments.setMinLines(3);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:maxLines="3"` with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this way it will work

```
 android:minLines="1"
   android:maxLines="3"
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your `EditText` with height `wrap_content`

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edComments"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:minLines="1"
   android:maxLines="3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edComments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Write your comment here"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:maxLength="140"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```